# In React Native Cloud Messaging, quiet and background mode, two notifications appear (one from Firebase and the other from Notifee)

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

In React Native Cloud Messaging, quiet and background mode, two notifications appear (one from Firebase and the other from Notifee). And when i click on notifee notification app not opening, but if click on firebase notification app opening and also possible to redirect specific screen. how can i implement this into notifee notificaton.

=======This is my onDisplayNotification (notifee) function========

```
export async function onDisplayNotification(data:any) {
    // Request permissions (required for iOS)

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        await notifee.requestPermission();
    }

    // Create a channel (required for Android)
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
        id: data?.data?.channel_id,
        name: data?.data?.channel_name,
        sound: data?.data?.sound_name,
        // importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });

    // Display a notification
    await notifee.displayNotification({
        title: data?.notification.title,
        body: data?.notification.body,

        android: {
            smallIcon: 'ic_launcher',
            channelId,
            color: BlueColor,
        },
    });

}
```

=========This is my noficationListner function which i called in Homescreen.======

```
export async function notificationListner() {
      //=========== Foreground state messages(when user using app open stage)===========
      const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
        console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', remoteMessage);

        
        //============= showing notification on notifee ===============
       await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);

    });
    //=========== Foreground state messages(when user using app open stage)==============



    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
        );

        // setTimeout(() => {
        //     NavigationService.navigate('Menu')
        // }, 1200)

        // navigation to  specific screen
        // if (!!remoteMessage?.data && remoteMessage?.data?.redirect_to == "Menu") {
        //     setTimeout(() => {
        //         NavigationService.navigate("Menu", { data: remoteMessage?.data })
        //     }, 1200)
        // }

    });

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(remoteMessage => {
            if (remoteMessage) {
                console.log(
                    'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
                    remoteMessage.notification,
                );
            }

        });






      return unsubscribe;


}
```

===========this is my background handler which i called into index.js============

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
await onDisplayNotification(remoteMessage);
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});
```

## In foreground mode notifee working fine. but in background and quite mode two notifications appear (one from Firebase and the other from Notifee).

**I send notification this format:**

```
{
    "registration_ids":[
   device-tokens......
    ],
    "notification":{
        "body":"Test notificaton body",
        "title":"Test notification title!"
        
    },
    "data": {
    "channel_id": "demo-channel",
    "channel_name": "demo-channel",
    "sound_name": "default"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) has this to say:

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

So when a message arrives while the app is backgrounded and the message has a `notification` property, that notification will be displayed by the system. There is no way to configure your code to display this notification.

If you want to always handle display of the message yourself, you should **not** send a `notification` message and only send `data` messages. You can of course put the same values in the `data` message, so that your code can get them from there.